# I'm having problems with File.WriteAllLines in C#

Tags: c#

*I understand that I need a contents array string but I'm having trouble implementing it.

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
string[] array = File.WriteAllLines("settings.cfg");
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    string text = array[i];
    if (!text.StartsWith("/") && text.Contains(":"))
    {
        string[] array2 = text.Split(new char[]
        {
            ':'
        });
        dictionary.Add(array2[0], array2[1]);
    }
}
```

*How would you implement `string[]` contents?

Comment: You're not giving any lines to `WriteAllLines`.

Comment: Perhaps you want `File.ReadAllLines` rather than `File.WriteAllLines`?

Comment: I was trying to make this code `File.WriteAllLines` in the Directory and such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When implementing such tasks, try using *Linq*. You have to

1. *Read* the file
2. *Filter out* lines
3. *Represent* each line as key and value (just split in your case)
4. *Materialize* the result as dictionary

Something like this:

```
   var dictionary = File
     .ReadLines("settings.cfg")
     .Where(line => !line.StartWith("/") && line.Contains(":"))
     .Select(line => line.Split(new char[] {':'}))
     .ToDictionary(items => items[0], items => items[1]);
```

In case you want `Dictionary<string, string[]>` as a result

> "How would you implement `string[]` contents?"

all you have to do is to modify the last line:

```
   var dictionary = File
     .ReadLines("settings.cfg")
     .Where(line => !line.StartWith("/") && line.Contains(":"))
     .Select(line => line.Split(new char[] {':'}))
     .ToDictionary(items => items[0], items => items.Skip(1).ToArray());
```

**Edit:** In case you want to save existing collection into a file, via `File.WriteAllLines` the right syntax is

```
  string[] SaveStrings = ...

  File.WriteAllLines("settings.cfg", SaveStrings);
```

Comment: I figured out the problem I wanted to WriteAllLines to a text file to save some settings in my project I used
File.WriteAllLines("settings.cfg");

Comment: this was my solution.
string[] savesettings = { "string1", "string2", "etc" };
File.WriteAllLines("settings.cfg", savesettings);